# Cloud TPU - Migrating off of older TF versions

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-tpu

If I am a Cloud TPU user and I have several TPU nodes with older TF versions (<=2.6.x) which are soon to be deprecated, is it possible to get support from the Cloud TPU team with migration? Please assign this issue the highest priority possible as the communicated deprecation date (6/30) is fast approaching.

Answer (score 0):

can you be more specific on what kind of support you need? Please try to create a tpu VM and upgrade you tensorflow version. Then you can solve issues/errors if they arise step by step and we can try to help if we know what's the error specificaly.